# Passing "-no-undefined" to Libtool LDFLAG

Tags: mingw32, libtool, mingw-w64, autogen

I am building a dll using MSys and Mingw on windows. The source for project only provides a autogen.sh, configure.ac and makefile.am. 
To generate the makefiles, you run autogen.sh then ./configure. I then go and manually add `-no-undefined` to the LDFLAGS in the makefile. This is not ideal, during the generation of the makefiles, this LDFLAGS should be set correctly.

Somewhere I have to change a configuration file, so that when the makefiles is generated the LDFLAGS is correctly set.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to set it in `Makefile.am`. If your library declaration looked something like this:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = foo.c
```

You'd add this line:

```
libfoo_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined
```

Comment: This isn't ideal IMO, because it adds it for windows and for linux, doesn't it? Only on windows, one needs this, so I would have expected that it should be done differently!

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to [Jack Kelly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15170289/3662499), you can define `AM_LDFLAGS` in the applicable Makefile.am like,

```
AM_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined
```

to pass the flag to the linker for all of your library rules (if so desired, to avoid repetition).

---

Note that the [Autom4ke manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-Variables.html) states that,

> In some situations, this is not used, in preference to the per-executable (or per-library) _LDFLAGS.

The wording here is not terribly clear, however, the [section on libtool flags](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Libtool-Flags.html#Libtool-Flags) states,

> If ‘library_LIBTOOLFLAGS’ is not defined, then the variable AM_LIBTOOLFLAGS is used instead.

Clearly stated by Calcote in his [*Autotools*](https://nostarch.com/autotools2e),

> The existence of a per-product variable overrides Automake's use of the per-makefile variable, so you need to add the per-makefile variable to the per-product variable in order to have the per-makefile variable affect that product [...].

This statement is accompanied by the example,

```
AM_CFLAGS = ... some flags ...
...
prog1_CFLAGS = ... more flags ... $(AM_CFLAGS)
...
```